# docker api ContainerExecInspect cannot get correct exit code

Tags: linux, shell, go, docker

I am using docker engine-api(github.com/docker/engine-api) to execute some command

I use client.ContainerExecCreate  and then client.ContainerExecInspect to run my command and then get the command exit code(I run multiple commands in the same container so the exit code get from ContainerInspect is useless for me.)

This is my function use to execute command in container

http://pastebin.com/rTNVuv9T

but ContainerExecInspect return wrong values sometime, because sometimes ContainerExecInspect is called before the command exit and it said exit code is zero, which is wrong

And I wrote a testcase to test it

http://pastebin.com/PED1Rf4k

And the result will not be 233, it will be 0

I have set ExecConfig.Detach = true and ExecStartCheck.Detach = true, but no helps

Is there any way to wait until the command exit then get the exit code?

Addition:

For some of my command running is shell script not a executable, so I think I need to prefix /bin/bash, and wait the **container** exit, is not what I want, I want to wait the **command** exit, and the container is still running

Comment: You're "command" is `/bin/bash`,  so you're getting the exit code from the bash process. If you want the exit code from the command, run the command directly. You also need to wait for the container to stop before reading the exit code.

Comment: The fact is I can get the correct exit code sometime(not the command in the testcase, I mean another command), so I don't think it's a matter of command "/bin/bash" and thanks :)

Comment: @VOID001, JimB is correct, /bin/bash will give exit codes like 233 when a child exits and it is suppose to exit as well.  Docker is running a exec.Command of /bin/bash in that case. So if you change it to a different command, the exit code is the code that command exits with.

Comment: Yes, in this case bash returns from the `exit` call, or it will return the code from the final command, but depending on what you're providing as the argument to `-c`, you may not get what you expect. Regardless, you wait for the _container_ to stop the get the exit code. I don't know wich client package you're using, but did you search for `Wait` in the documentation (waiting on a container is a standard part of the API)?

Comment: I use the official github.com/docker/engine-api and I am not waiting the "container" to exit so the containerWait is not useful for me, Cause the command exit but the container  is stll running

Comment: just FYI, that package is marked as deprecated, and you should use the current client from `github.com/docker/docker/client`. I don't think there's any way to wait on a process run via `exec` inside a running container, other than polling its `Running` status.  The method for waiting on a docker process is by executing it as a container. Exec is targeted more for interactive inspection of a container (the primary use of `docker exec` is starting an interactive shell or quick changes for troubleshooting), and there isn't really any process control around it.

Answer (score 0):

I think now I can solve my problem

The main point is when using containerExecAttach it will exposed the hijacked connection and, I can judge whether the command exit by read from the connection until EOF

There are a few point to set then

1. Should set ExecConfig AttachStdout to true
2. Then read from hijacked conn

Here is a sample code

```
atinfo, err := cli.ContainerExecAttach(ctx, execID, ec)

// error handling

defer atinfo.Close()
c = atinfo.Conn 

one := make([]byte, 1)
_, err = c.Read(one)

if err == io.EOF {
    println("Connection closed")
}
```

This will wait until the command execute complete

ExecConfig is set to

```
ec.Detach = false
ec.Tty = false
ec.AttachStdout = true
```

Comment: The code is using deprecated github.com/docker/engine-api, I will try it with github.com/docker/docker again and post my result